# Invoke AWS REST API in java-script

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am trying to execute AWS Endpoint using nodejs (aws-sdk). First, I am able to generate session token for Service Account which has access to execute the API.

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ "accessKeyId": "<>", "secretAccessKey": "<>", "region": "us-west" });
var sts = new AWS.STS();
var response = {};
sts.assumeRole({
    RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::170000000000:role/service-account',
    RoleSessionName: 'AssumtaseRole'
}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) { // an error occurred
        var error = {}
        response.message = err.originalError.message,
            response.errno = err.originalError.errno,
            response.code = 404;
        console.log(response);
    } else { // successful response
        response.code = 200,
            response.accesskey = data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
            response.secretkey = data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
            response.sessiontoken = data.Credentials.SessionToken,
            console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Now I am trying to execute the endpoint using the above session token. If test session token using postman, I am able to execute the API but not sure how to do it using (aws-sdk) or ('aws-api-gateway-client')

I tried to execute using simple HTPPS request but getting error: Here is the code:

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var apigClientFactory = require('aws-api-gateway-client').default;

AWS.config.update({ "accessKeyId": "<>", "secretAccessKey": "<>", "region": "us-west" });

var sts = new AWS.STS();
var response = {};
sts.assumeRole({
    RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::170000000000:role/service_account',
    RoleSessionName: 'AssumtaseRole'
}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) { // an error occurred
        var error = {}
        response.message = err.originalError.message,
            response.errno = err.originalError.errno,
            response.code = 404;
        console.log(response);
    } else { // successful response
        response.code = 200,
            response.accesskey = data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
            response.secretkey = data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
            response.sessiontoken = data.Credentials.SessionToken,
            console.log(response);
        var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
            invokeUrl: "https://some-endpoint.com", // REQUIRED
            accessKey: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId, // REQUIRED
            secretKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey, // REQUIRED
            sessiontoken: data.Credentials.SessionToken,
            region: "us-west", // REQUIRED: The region where the AapiKeyloyed.
            retries: 4,
            retryCondition: (err) => { // OPTIONAL: Callback to further control if request should be retried.  Uses axon-retry plugin.
                return err.response && err.response.status === 500;

            }
        });

        var pathParams = "";
        var pathTemplate = "/agent/registration"; // '/api/v1/sites'
        var method = "post"; // 'POST';
        var additionalParams = ""; //queryParams & Headers if any

        var body = {
            "agent_number": "1200",
            "agent_name": "Test"
        };

        apigClient.invokeApi(pathParams, pathTemplate, method, additionalParams, body)
            .then(function(result) {
                console.log(result)

            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error)

            });
        // console.log(output);

    }
});
```

Here is the error:

```js
     data:
      { message: 'The security token included in the request is invalid.' } } }
```

Thanks in advance.

Thank You Kiran

Comment: I guess you could just use any of the http libraries that are offered for nodejs, doesn't need to be anything aws-specific.

Comment: please, an example would be helpful.

Comment: All I'm saying that if you can do it with postman then you can do the same with [`request`](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native) (or similar) in node

Comment: Like @Bergi says, you should be able to send an HTTP request to the endpoint. A simple library that can help with that is [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Comment: @bergi & mrstack99 thanks for the quick response. I have updated the original post.

Comment: Is it possible `sessiontoken` is case sensitive?

Comment: I don't disagree that `axios` and `request` are good libraries. But accessing the API end point with AWS credentials requires a signature generation and sent part of the request. Postman does it automatically when you select the `Authorization` type as  `AWS Signature` and provide the accessKey, Secretkey and sessionToken.  The npm library `aws-api-gateway-client` also supports the signature generation. If we use `axios` or `request` directly, the signature should be generated separately. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change `sessiontoken` to `sessionToken`. that will fix your issue. I have tested the code on my machine.

When i tested with `sessiontoken` i also received the error `The security token included in the request is invalid.`. It worked when i changed it to the correct key which is `sessionToken`.

here is simplified code. When i tested, I have hard coded accessKey, secretKey and sessionToken.

```
var apigClientFactory = require('aws-api-gateway-client').default;
var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
    invokeUrl:'https://api-url.com', // REQUIRED
    accessKey: '', // REQUIRED
    secretKey: '', // REQUIRED
    sessionToken: '', //OPTIONAL: If you are using temporary credentials you must include the session token
    region: 'ap-southeast-2', // REQUIRED: The region where the API is deployed.
    systemClockOffset: 0, // OPTIONAL: An offset value in milliseconds to apply to signing time
    retries: 4, // OPTIONAL: Number of times to retry before failing. Uses axon-retry plugin.
    retryCondition: (err) => { // OPTIONAL: Callback to further control if request should be retried.  Uses axon-retry plugin.
      return err.response && err.response.status === 500;
    }
});


(() => {
  apigClient.invokeApi(null, `/hello`, 'GET')
  .then(function(result){
    console.log('result: ', result)
      //This is where you would put a success callback
  }).catch( function(result){
    console.log('result: ', result)
      //This is where you would put an error callback
  });
})()
```